# What is the Best Practice between burguer menu & full screen menu in a react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, menu

So i have a website, it is responsive, in small screens the menu is open clicking in a burguer button, when there is enough space the menu is visible in the header and the burguer button dissapear.

My question is what is the best practise to handle this componetes (the burguer is a components that change a context state `showMenu`).

Should I have 2 diferents Menu components `MenuResponsive || MenuInHeader` & mount unmount them dependimg on the screen size or only one component with a ton of CSS.
Im using css.module just in case.

thanks

Comment: Check material design tutorial [link](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer#usage).

Answer (score 1):

The beauty is that you have options. If the button is going to be reused a lot, I would create a separate component. If not, then I would probably manage responsive design with CSS using media queries or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, because there is to many options i wondering what is the best practice in this case.  My doubts are regarding the menu components that contain the links, the burger button is a component that toggles the state  showMenu